# Unexpected exception upon serialization continuation

Tags: google-apps-script

i wrote a Google apps spreadsheet script that is supposed to pick up a pdf from my drive and email it as an attachment to many people, to each of whom a unique file is to be emailed. The data is in a spreadsheet. The first column has the email address of the recepient, the second column has the the pdf file name that has to be attached and the third column has name of the person.

```
function sendPDFs() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow() -1;   // Number of rows to process

// Fetch the range of cells A2:C3
var nummails = 0
var numdrive = 0
var checkCol = 4
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)

// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column

var subject = "Some subject";

var body = 'Dear ' + row[2] + '\n\nPlease find your ' + subject + ' \n\nThank you \n\n XYZ'

var attachment = row[1];    // Second column.

var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(attachment); // Get all files with name.
var blobs = []; // Array for attachment.

// Move files into blobs
while (files.hasNext()) {
 var file = files.next();
  blobs.push(file.getAs("application/PDF"));
}

// dont sent to invalid email ids or those without email ids
 if (emailAddress == "" || emailAddress.indexOf("@") <= -1){
   sheet.getRange(i+2, checkCol+1).setValue('Not Emailed')
    numdrive = numdrive+1
    }
  else{
    Utilities.sleep(1000)
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body, {attachments: blobs, name: "XYZ" })
    sheet.getRange(i+2, checkCol+1).setValue('Emailed')
    nummails = nummails +1
  }

   }
 Browser.msgBox( nummails+ " Mails sent successfully.")
}
```

i get the error Unexpected exception upon serialization continuation. However, the emails are sent. Looks like the code works but i dont know why the error. I have seen the existing threads with the same error but they dint help.

Apppreciate any help on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that your main loop isn't doing what you expected : the value of i was wrong in the loop. I changed the loop definition as follows

```
  for (var i=0 ; i<data.length ; ++i) {
```

please give it a try and let us know what happens.

Comment: I replaced the for loop by the above. Still getting the same error.

Comment: hmmm... I get another error : "We're sorry, no servers are currently available. Please wait a bit and try again" when trying to get something from the pdf...

Comment: Hey, are you using new spreadsheet format ? : if yes see https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579  It does explain my issue at least.

Answer (score 0):

First, have a look to 'Execution transcript' in script editor menu. You can find the reason of error there.

> Every time you run a script, Google Apps Script records an execution
>   transcript, which is a record of each call to a Google Apps Script
>   service that is made while the script runs. These transcripts can help
>   you to understand which actions your script performed. To view the
>   execution transcript click on **View > Execution transcript** in the
>   menu bar after the script finishes running.

I usualy get these errors (exceptions) when I reach some Google Apps script limits (quotas). See quotas here: https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard (switch to tab quotas).